# stack.horizobu.com - an exploration engine

Tags: app, search, data-dump

### Screenshot

[image: Query on stack.horizobu.com for "jquery visible"]

### About

stack.horizobu.com is a search engine for the various Stack Exchange question and answer sites. horizobu assists you in your search by suggesting related query terms. The query terms allow you to explore a topic that you are unfamiliar with and therefore helps you to find the answer to your question. You can collect results and share them with your friends; e.g. a results for ["jquery visible"](http://stack.horizobu.com/s/80527087b0893144aa09776d3f35aca6#).

stack.horizobu.com is designed for people that are looking for a dedicated search engine for the Stack Exchange sites.

#### Web Site

http://stack.horizobu.com

#### Platform

Any platform that runs a reasonably new browser.

### Contact

- **Idea & Concept:** Sam Zurcher, Werner Hartmann (Wettingen, Switzerland)
- **Design:** Beate Niedhart, Florian Stolzenhain, Oliver Spieker (fuklab Berlin, Germany)
- **Business:** Andreas Feuz (Zürich, Switzerland)
- **Contributions:** Michael Hielscher, Nando Stöcklin, Diana Jurjevic, Oliver Ott, Raimond Reichert, Ruedi Arnold

The horizobu team can be reached with the [feedback form](http://hrzb.ch/feedback/index-en.html).

### Code

horizobu is written in Java (using Spring) and Javascript (using JQuery and Google Closure Library / Google Closure Compiler) and makes use of the publicly available Stack Exchange data dump. The data dump is processed using Hadoop and the result is stored in [s3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). Hosted on [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) using [scalr.net](http://www.scalr.net) / nginx / Tomcat / memcached.

Comment: The interface is **awesome**.

Comment: I second the motion that the UI is crazy good. I'm not sure if I understand the blue rainbow logo. Does that represent the horizon or something?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the blue logo symbolizes the horizon. We're glad you like the UI :-)

Comment: Tried to visit today and the server can't be found.

Comment: We have terminated the project. Thanks for your interest. Documentation can be found at http://horizobu.ch/